# Comments disappeared from "Jagged Earth" question

Tags: discussion

This is not a big issue, but did come as a surprise.

There is an answer I posted to a question about a mountainous planet:  [What would produce the most uneven but earthlike planetary surface?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/94369/what-would-produce-the-most-uneven-but-earthlike-planetary-surface/94375#94375)

A kind gentleman added a comment pointing out I'd not discussed earthquakes in this scenario.  So I added a comment saying I would, then edited the question.  Some short time later, both comments had disappeared.

I imagine that someone noticed that interaction and removed the now-unnecessary comments -- they'd done their work -- but I just wanted to make sure that that was the custom.

Oh yes, the actual question...  **Is this expected behavior?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting obsolete comments is pretty normal, either because somebody flagged them as such or because a moderator came across them in normal use of the site.  Clearing out obsolete comments makes it easier for new comments to be seen.

I didn't handle this particular case, but yes, that's expected behavior.  Nothing bad happened, just routine maintenance.